# "Static methods are death to testability" - alternatives for alternative constructors?

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, design-patterns, static-methods

It is being said that ["static methods are death to testability"](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/). If that is so, what is a viable alternative pattern for the below?

```
class User {

    private $phone,
            $status = 'default',
            $created,
            $modified;

    public function __construct($phone) {
        $this->phone    = $phone;
        $this->created  = new DateTime;
        $this->modified = new DateTime;
    }

    public static function getByPhone(PDO $pdo, $phone) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `phone` = :phone');
        $stmt->execute(compact('phone'));
        if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
            return false;
        }

        $record         = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user           = new self($record['phone']);
        $user->status   = $record['status'];
        $user->created  = new DateTime($record['created']);
        $user->modified = new DateTime($record['modified']);
        return $user;
    }

    public function save(PDO $pdo) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO `users` (`phone`, `status`, `created`, `modified`)
                  VALUES         (:phone,  :status,  :created,  :modified)
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status`   = :status,
                                     `modified` = :modified');

        $data = array(
            'phone'    => $this->phone,
            'status'   => $this->status,
            'created'  => $this->created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        return $stmt->execute($data);
    }

    ...

}
```

This is just a cut down example. The class has a few more methods and properties and there's more validation when writing to the database etc. The guiding design principle behind this class is that it models a user as an object. Some of the object's properties cannot be modified after it has been created, like the phone number (which acts as a primary id), the date the user was created and so on. Other properties can only be altered according to strict business rules, which all have strictly validating setters and getters.

The object does not represent a database record per se, the database is only seen as *one* possible form of permanent storage. As such, a database connector is not stored in the object but rather needs to be injected every time the object needs to interact with the database.

When a new user is created, this looks like:

```
$user = new User('+123456789');
```

When an existing user is restored from permanent storage, that looks like:

```
$pdo  = new PDO('...');
$user = User::getByPhone($pdo, '+123456789');
```

If I were to take the "death to testability" line seriously, this is supposedly bad. I am perfectly able to test this object though, since it is fully dependency injected and the `static` methods have no state. How could I do this any differently and avoid the use of `static` methods? Or rather, what exactly argues against `static` in this case? What makes this particular use of `static` methods so hard to test?

Comment: For the above case, I'd go with a [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

Comment: In this particular case static method is `death to extensibility`. You better tie your application parts via interfaces, not implementations

Comment: @Phil If I understand correctly, the Repository mostly seems to abstract the database queries, which I'd agree would be a useful thing to do. How would I initiate `private` properties without a static constructor through while still keeping all my privates encapsulated?

Comment: @zerkms At *some* point though I *have* to "hardcode" the use of `User` somewhere. If `new User` is acceptable, why isn't `User::getByPhone`? They both act as constructors.

Comment: @deceze There's a couple of ways; You could implement public *setters* for those properties or [use Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003452/how-does-doctrine2-set-the-id-values/8003529#8003529) to set them (have a look at the Doctrine ORM v2+)

Comment: @deceze: pass the data to the entities' constructor

Comment: @deceze: because `new User` is supposed to be used in some limited amount of places. In all other cases you could be satisfied with `IUser`

Comment: @Phil Setters means that some unalterable properties become alterable though, which is against business rules (yes, you can argue that if it's a business rule, you shouldn't do it, but being able to prevent it by design is more powerful IMO). To use reflection, I'd have to put the initiation-by-reflection logic somewhere. I guess this drifts towards a Factory pattern. But again, that distributes the business logic across different parts of the code. Rather, why exactly is *this* use of `static` supposedly hard to test?

Comment: Could you guys write this up as an answer, please? :)

Comment: +1 for an excellent question. I feel like I have accidentally stumbled into a MENSA convention!

Comment: @zerkms Passing all attributes to the constructor would a) make for an enormous constructor and b) muddle the waters with regards to non-modifiable properties.

Comment: @deceze: pass an array. There is nothing bad with parametrizing your container objects with its properties

Comment: @zerkms But again, a *newly registered user* is only required to give a certain minimal amount of information. The `User` constructor reflects that. While that user is using the system, over time certain aspects of his state will change (`status` will change etc). This is completely enforced by not being able to put the user object into a certain state without going through certain steps (setters). This makes business logic extremely easy to test with very little code. If the constructor would accept data for all properties, it would take a lot more code to validate the state of the object.

Comment: @deceze: how so? You still need to validate each property, as in any other implementation. In your sample there is no validation at all. So should be nothing in a constructor.

Comment: @zerkms As I wrote, this is just an excerpt. There's a lot more validation going on, which I'm omitting for the sake of focusing on the question *"What's particularly hard to test about this `static` method?"*

Comment: @deceze: I've already pointed a case below - when you test something that depends on your static method - you're in stuck. That is why relying on interfaces and dependency injection is good.

Comment: @deceze: have you seen my conversation with drrcknlsn below? ;-) What do you think? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I didn't read the whole thing, but I understand both arguments. Normal static *function calls* **can** be a problem to testability. They don't necessarily have to be, but there's always potential for them to become one later. That's fine. Do let me remind you again though that my question is about the *construction of objects*, which I will continue to argue do not make testability any better or worse by using static methods. :)

Comment: @deceze: argh! construction of objects is just one of many scenarios, which can lead to the issues as well ;-) In your example you not only construct (instantiate) objects but also perform db queries ;-)

Comment: @zerkms But that doesn't matter, since the DB dependency is injected! You cannot mock `new Obj` any better than you can `Obj::new`, and you can mock both cases with a factory!!! Argh!!!11one ;-)

Comment: @deceze: this **violates** encapsulation, Argh! Outer classes should now know about details of implementation of inner classes ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I still don't get that argument. It really is just a syntactical difference in how to make an object. It doesn't change the fact that you *do* instantiate or mock an object nor does it make it any harder or easier to mock an object. Please give me a complete example, including actually instantiating an object and demonstrating any deficiencies in either method. Use my answer as template! Arghl!eleven! ;)

Comment: @deceze: http://pastebin.com/FpBc1hBu --- here static object creator would be much more difficult to test rather than mocked non-static one ;-) Easily tested code: http://pastebin.com/cUjmbWvr - you are not able to do something even close to this code with just static

Comment: @zerkms But those are not the same things. I am saying `new User` vs. `User::new`. The correct altered snippet would be http://pastebin.com/w9RViVYC.

Comment: 6 answers and no accepted? Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Mike I'm still working this one out internally and have some things to go over when I have some spare time. :)

Comment: @deceze: Roger that. Added as favorite, interested in solution.

Comment: @zerkms Here finally is my exhaustive take on the matter. Hope you agree. :) [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: @mike It's been a while, but I've worked out the issue... :) [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mostly a summary of (my perspective of) [the chat that ensued between me and @zerkms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6954/discussion-between-zerkms-and-deceze):

The point of contention is actually this:

```
public function doSomething($id) {
    $user = User::getByPhone($this->pdo, $id);

    // do something with user

    return $someData;
}
```

This makes it hard to test `doSomething` since it hardcodes the `User` class, which may or may not have a lot of dependencies. But this is in fact the same as instantiating the object using a non-static method:

```
public function doSomething($id) {
    $user = new User;
    $user->initializeFromDb($this->pdo, $id);

    // do something with user

    return $someData;
}
```

We're not using a static method, but it's still unmockable. Actually, it got worse.
The answer is to use a factory:

```
public function doSomething($id) {
    $user = $this->UserFactory->byPhone($id);

    // do something with user

    return $someData;
}
```

Now the factory can be dependency injected and mocked and the `User` class is no longer hardcoded. You may or may not think this overkill, but it certainly improves mockability.

That does not change the fact though that this factory may very well instantiate the actual user object using a static method:

```
public function byPhone($id) {
    return User::getByPhone($this->db, $id);
}
```

There's no difference between using a static method or a regular constructor here.

```
$user = new User($db, $id);
$user = User::getByPhone($db, $id);
```

Both expressions return an instance of `User` and both "hardcode" the `User` class. Which simply needs to happen at some point anyway.

For my use case, a `static` constructor method makes the most sense for the object. And as was demonstrated, `static` methods are not the problem. Where to *call* them is the point of contention, not that they exist at all. And I have yet to see a convincing argument for not using static constructors, since they can be wrapped in a factory, which alleviates any problem with mockability, the same as it does for regular object instantiation.

Comment: For `User::getByPhone()` to have a dependency (like a `PDO` connection) that isn't injected through a method argument, it has to *maintain some sort of state*.  Static methods only cause problems when you allow them to maintain/use state.  As long as your static methods do not do this, then testability is not affected whatsoever.  Please see my answer.

Comment: @drrcknlsn That is true, **but**: static methods cannot be mocked. Even if they're 100% dependency injected and the dependencies can be mocked, the static method itself cannot be mocked. This may be important if the method is doing a lot of work or the (injected) dependencies are so extensive that they're difficult to mock. In that case it can be a lot easier to just mock the method itself, which makes it easier to test code *that uses this method*. That is all true. Only **object construction** using a static method is a special case, which does not affect mockability.

Comment: After some abstinence I had a good long look at all the answers here again. Unfortunately none really address the issue I posed in the question, which is about static constructors and why they're bad for testability. I hate to do so with all the good things written by others here, but I'll accept my own answer on this. I have also worked this issue into an article: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Answer (score 2):

As long as OP asked about general issue, and not asked how to improve his particular code - I'll try to answer using some abstract and tiny classes:

Well, it is not more difficult to test static methods themselves, but it **is** more difficult to test the methods that use static methods.

Let's see the difference on small example.

Let's say we have a class

```
class A
{
    public static function weird()
    {
        return 'some things that depends on 3rd party resource, like Facebook API';
    }
}
```

It does some work that requires setting up additional environment (specifying API keys in this case) and internet connection to FB API services. It will take some time to test this method (just because of network and API lags), but it is definitely easy enough to test it.

Now, we implement a class that uses `A::weird()` method:

```
class TestMe
{
    public function methodYouNeedToTest()
    {
        $data = A::weird();

        return 'do something with $data and return';
    }
}
```

For now - we cannot test `TestMe::methodYouNeedToTest()` without additional steps required to make `A::weird()` worked. Yes, instead of testing `methodYouNeedToTest` we also need to do things that are not directly related to this class, but to another.

If we followed another way from the very begin:

```
class B implements IDataSource
{
    public function weird()
    {
        return 'some things that depends on 3rd party resource, like Facebook API';
    }
}
```

you see - the key difference here is that we implemented the `IDataSource` interface and made method normal, not static. For now we could rewrite our code above in this way:

```
class TestMe
{
    public function methodYouNeedToTest(IDataSource $ds)
    {
        $data = $ds->weird();

        return 'do something with $data and return';
    }
}
```

And now we don't rely on specific implementation but we do on an interface. And now we can easily mock datasource.

Such abstractions help keeping our tests focusing more on the testing itself rather than on creating necessary environment.

Such steps helps us to have our **unit tests** fast. While we still could have acceptance, load and functional tests (but it is another story) that test that our *application* works as expected

Comment: You can mock concrete classes using [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery)

Comment: @Phil: can it mock **static** methods?

Comment: That's dandy and all, but that means the integrity of my `User` objects is broken. The class is currently written in a completely self-contained fashion which allows me to say *"Whenever I have an object of type `User`, it's guaranteed to be in a good, consistent state."* That makes type hints useful and error handling simple. Which is a pretty huge point of OOP. If I need to be able to create "empty" instances which I need to initialize using a separate non-static call, that guarantee goes out the window. In your example, where *do* you instantiate `$ds`?

Comment: @deceze: it comes from dependency injection tool (and in tests I manually create and pass a mock)

Comment: "The class is currently written in a completely self-contained fashion" --- it doesn't matter. Any class that uses your `User::staticmethod()` will be difficult to test. It is a fact, and that is what you asked about ;-)

Comment: "Which is a pretty huge point of OOP" --- OOP is a paradigm around inheritance, encapsulation and **polymorphism**. Static classes and methods are not polymorphic

Comment: Then I'll ask again what the difference between `new User` and `User::getByPhone` is. If you need to *mock the instantiation*, use a factory that can use static constructor methods. `$factory->fromDb('User', 'byPhone', 42)`.

Comment: Exactly, *encapsulation*. An object is responsible for its own members and internal status.

Comment: @deceze: uhm, I'm sorry, but are you kidding? In **my** example there is no `new`. Doesn't matter what your static method does - what does matter is that it is not possible to mock static class/method. You either ask a question about article and why static is evil (I've answered why) or go to your specific example and discuss why it is bad in your particular case :-)

Comment: "If you need to mock the instantiation" --- I **didn't say anything** about instantiation. Doesn't matter what and how static method returns

Comment: "Exactly, encapsulation. An object is responsible for its own members and internal status." --- that is just wrong. This doesn't justify static

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6954/discussion-between-zerkms-and-deceze)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're missing the point of the question then. I'm specifically asking how a static method acting as an object constructor is "hard to test".

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are only "death to testability" if they depend on state.  If you avoid writing such methods to begin with (which you should), then this issue simply goes away.

The `Math.abs()` example given is one of a *good* use of a static method.  It does not depend on state, therefor it is super easily tested.

That said, whether or not you think static methods *should* be used is another story.  Some people dislike their seemingly procedural nature.  I agree with those who say that OOP is a tool, not a goal.  If writing "proper" OO code doesn't make sense for a particular situation (e.g. `Math.abs()`), then *don't do it.*  I promise the boogey man won't eat your application just because you used a static method.  :-)

Comment: Even if you don't depend on state - it makes testing worse if other class use this static method. See my answer for details

Comment: @zerkms: That is not true, and your answer does not give any reason supporting that argument.  If `Foo::bar()` calls static method `Bar::baz()`, and `Bar::baz()` does not depend on state, then there is absolutely no reason `Foo::bar()` would be less testable.  In fact, every stock function in PHP is equivalent to a "static method".  Are you saying that any class method using a PHP function that doesn't depend on state (i.e. `strlen()`) is somehow less testable than those that don't?  That's absurd.

Comment: function could calculate 1 billion iterations of md5(). It takes a time. And `Foo::bar()` will be difficult to test just because it will take an hour to perform one test case. In the same time the function is stateless

Comment: Another example: the `Bar::baz()` function connects to remote *RESTful* service to evaluate some math. Still no state, terrible to test

Comment: @zerkms: The time it takes to process a method has nothing to do with it being static or not.  As far as your RESTful service argument, the web service would be a dependency.  If static method `Bar::baz()` doesn't include a way to inject that dependency, then your testability suffers because of an inability to inject (and thus, mock) the dependency **not because it's a static method.**

Comment: well, you can inject and mock object, but you cannot mock static method. Thus you need to wait for an hour to test the code. ". If static method Bar::baz() doesn't include a way to inject that dependency," --- if we test `Foo::bar()` we **shouldn't care** of dependencies of `Bar::baz()`, because in that way our tests would know more than it is necessary to write a test. This is what I said in my answer

Comment: What if there is A::b() static call that uses B::c() static call that uses C::d() static call and some of them have several dependencies? You would inject every dependency and mock them manually? Well, instead of testing your test case will contain several dozens of lines with mocks setup. While my code will have only mocking one (the upper level) object. Your tests will be more fragile as well - since they depend also on **implementation** of irrelevant classes.

Comment: @zerkms: If `Bar::baz()` is a static method, its only way of injecting dependencies is through arguments (i.e. `Bar::baz($webService)`).  Since this dependency is injected through the argument list, it's therefor in scope within `Foo::bar()`.  If it's in scope within `Foo::bar()`, that means either A) it can be injected in your testing of `Foo::bar()` in some way, or B) you're using uninjected dependencies in `Foo::bar()`, which is hurting your testability, **not because `Bar::baz()` is static.**

Comment: @zerkms: Re: your A/B/C example - Dependencies have to be mocked regardless of whether they're passed through nested mess of static or non-static methods.  You can't get away with "mocking one (upper level) object".  That upper level object will still need mocked dependencies needed by its methods.  The only thing you've done is encapsulate all the dependencies.  I won't disagree that this is *cleaner*, but it does not make static methods *less testable*.

Comment: " You can't get away with "mocking one (upper level) object"" --- no, I can. When I mock I follow the idea of hiding the behaviour, not the implementation. " That upper level object will still need mocked" --- nope, it need not. "but it does not make static methods less testable." --- it does. You would need to mock all the dependency tree (see - your code will depend on **implementation** much and will be very sensitive to any changes in whole tree), while mine will just mock one class on top of the tree.

Comment: " A) it can be injected in your testing of Foo::bar() in some way" --- I don't want to know about **any** dependencies of nested classes. I don't care of dependencies of nested classes, I test **outer** class. Your tests rely on something irrelevant to the tested code, mine - not.

Comment: " B) you're using uninjected dependencies in Foo::bar(), which is hurting your testability, not because Bar::baz() is static. " --- I don't care of injection into `Bar::baz()`. I don't test `Bar::baz()`, I do test `Foo::bar()` and I want to focus on `Foo::bar()` only. You advice to rewrite the code to make it testable (to inject dependencies from upper to lower levels), while *my code is testable from the very begin*, without any additional steps

Comment: If `A::b()` calls `B::c()`, and `B::c()` has some dependency, how do you propose to test `A::b()` without that dependency?  Static methods or not, you still have the same problem.  Either your dependencies are on the upper level object and `B::c()` uses `$this->dependency`, in which case you have to mock `$this->dependency`, or dependencies are injected into `B::c($dependency)` and you have to mock `$dependency`.  Either way, you have to mock the dependency.

Comment: I wouldn't have `A::b()`, I would have `$a->b()` and I just mock it, without resolving dependencies deeper. With static method I had an issue (maintaining the dependency tree manually), without static methods I don't have such

Comment: How would you change the code http://pastebin.com/6wDjdSC4 to have `Test::me()` testable?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/05S62JWd --- here is my solution. You see - I just added dependency injection in **one** place any my code **immediately** become testable. What would you do with the original code?

Comment: I understand now, but the problem only happens with dependency trees, not static methods.  For example, `Math.abs(-5)` has no dependency tree.  It would be no harder to test than `-5.abs()`.  Your argument only applies to a very small problem, I think.

Comment: `Math.abs(-5)` is stateless indeed but it is evaluated very fast, this hides the actual problem. When you would use `Md5::billionTimes($str);` - then you have the similar code, that is stateless as well, but works too long in testing environment, thus makes unit tests (that by definition should work in reasonable time) pointless. While `$md5->billionTimes($str);` haven't such problem, since we can mock it.

Comment: I've never run across a static method that ran for long enough for this to be an issue.  I still think you are arguing against static methods only because of worst-case scenarios that rarely happen.  That's not really fair to the majority of static methods that don't exhibit these fringe problems. :-)

Comment: ok, another example, not long working one: our static method just pulls some data from 3rd party data provider (Twitter API or Facebook API or LinkedIn API or Database, chosen by moon phase). And our tested method knows nothing about that data providers. What would you do? Would you open details of implementations to the upper level (encapsulation violations + making tests fragile)?

Comment: I wouldn't design such a method.  I would create `interface IDataProvider`, and class `TwitterDataProvider implements IDataProvider`, and then inject: `Foo::getData(IDataProvider $dataProvider)`.  Then I can mock `$dataProvider` and test `Foo::getData()` without worry.

Comment: No-no, you probably didn't get me :-) `Test::me()` class uses `data::provider()` and `data::provider()` **internally decides** (may be randomly, may be by phase of Moon) what and when to use ;-) How would you inject dependencies into `data::provider()` if you **don't know** which actual API will be used for this particular time? ;-)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TQ1MWvVS --- here is what I meant. How would you test `Test::me()` in this case? What changes would you introduce?

Comment: In your example, `Test::me()` is using an internal dependency (result from `data::provider()`).  Not using dependency injection is what is killing testability of `Test::me()` here, not static method usage.  Instead, `Test::me()` should accept a data provider argument, or there should be a `Test::setDataProvider()` static method to set a static `Test::$dataProvider` property which `Test::me()` can use.  Either way, we can inject the dependency and test without problems.

Comment: ". Not using dependency injection is what is killing testability of Test::me() here, not static method usage. " --- this is incorrect. We **could** test `test::me` if `data::source()` wasn't static. So static implementation in this case - isn't testable, but non-static **is testable**. And you cannot use `setDataProvider` because **you don't know** which one will be used. You will pass all providers? great, you've violated encapsulation rule and made your test dependent on implementation, which will fail in any changes of providers list (adding new)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Udvxcbwb --- you see - I **once again** changed just 2 lines and I have **perfectly testable** code. What would you change to have static testable? Still insisting that static doesn't change testability? Waiting for your code solution then ;-)

Comment: `Test::me() should accept a data provider argument` -- it cannot. We **know nothing** about data providers. The library is **enrypted** and shipped as obfuscated code :-S Still makes no sense? ;-) And even if we decrypt it - we see that it uses 100 different providers *randomly*. Would you instantiate all 100 and pass them there? Good luck then

Comment: There is no substitute for well-designed code.  I'm not going to argue that your method is better when dealing with badly designed code; it's quite obvious that it is.  But when you're dealing with well designed code, static methods do not hurt testability.  I prefer to use well designed code, and would never use a 3rd party library that horrible. :-P

Comment: haha, I've given 3 different test cases and no one have satisfied you. Well, seems like I have no arguments yet ;-) If you think that passing dependencies through all the dependency tree is better than just using non-static methods, it's your with ;-) Was glad to discuss

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, I'd implement a repository pattern for this case.

For example, `User` would be a simple model with read-only properties

```
class User {
    private $phone,
            $status = 'default',
            $created,
            $modified;

    public function __construct($phone) {
        $this->setPhone($phone);
        $this->created  = new DateTime;
        $this->modified = new DateTime;
    }

    private function setPhone($phone) {
        // validate phone here

        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function getPhone() {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getModified() {
        return $this->modified;
    }
}
```

Your repository interface could then look like this

```
interface UserRepository {

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function findByPhone($phone);

    public function save(User $user);
}
```

A concrete implementation of this interface could look something like this

```
class DbUserRepository implements UserRepository {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function findByPhone($phone) {
        // query db and get results, return null for not found, etc

        $user = new User($phone);

        // example setting the created date
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('User');

        $reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('created');
        $reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);

        $created = new DateTime($res['created']); // create from DB value (simplified)
        $reflectionProperty->setValue($user, $created);

        return $user;
    }

    public function save(User $user) {
        // prepare statement and fetch values from model getters
        // execute statement, return result, throw errors as exceptions, etc
    }
}
```

The cool thing here is that you can implement many different repositories, all with different persistence strategies (XML, test data, etc)

Comment: Sounds good, and I agree that the storage mechanism can certainly be abstracted better. But, I could do the same by abstracting the storage object the other way around. `User::save(Storage $storage)`, where `Storage` can be subclassed to different backends. The `User` class can use that to get and set its data from storage, and still be in charge of all its own properties. Setting properties by reflection means the business logic for the user is distributed among different classes, which I want to avoid.

Comment: What would be the point of that? `User` would just call `Storage::save($this)`. Build your domain model as it has to be but don't include any persistence logic. If the persistence layer has to use reflection due to business logic in the model, I don't see a problem there.

Comment: No, `User` would call `Storage::save(array('phone' => $this->phone, ...))`. It would just hand its *data* over for storage, the storage does not need to know about the *object*. The point being that the `User` needs to enforce certain business rules (state), think FSM. Allowing other parts of the code to alter the internal state of the object makes it harder to enforce a correct state.

Answer (score 1):

I think the citation you give has a good point but takes too hard a line.

Your static method is what he calls a "leaf" method. In this case I think you are fine, as long as your static method doesn't have any external dependencies.

The alternative is a data mapper, an object which is aware of the relationship between `User` and how it is stored in the database. Example:

```
class UserDBMapper {
    protected $pdo;
    protected $userclass;
    function __construct(PDO $pdo, $userclass) {
        $this->db = $db;
        // Note we can even dependency-inject a User class name if it obeys the interface that UserMapper expects.
        // You can formalize this requirement with instanceof, interface_exists() etc if you are really keen...
        $this->userclass = $userclass;  
    }

    function getByPhone($phone) {
        // fetches users from $pdo
        $stmt = $this->db->query(...);
        $userinfo = $stmt->fetch()....
        // creates an intermediary structure that can be used to create a User object
        // could even just be an array with all the data types converted, e.g. your DateTimes.
        $userargs = array(
            'name' => $userinfo['name'],
            'created' => $userinfo['created'],
            // etc
        );

        // Now pass this structure to the $userclass, which should know how to create itself from $userargs
        return new $this->userclass($userargs);
    }

    function save($userobj) {
        // save method goes in the Mapper, too. The mapper knows how to "serialize" a User to the DB.
        // User objects should not have find/save methods, instead do:
        // $usermapper->save($userobj);
    }   
}
```

This is a very powerful pattern (e.g., you need no longer have 1-1 type<->table, instance<->row correspondence like the Active Record pattern requires), and you can completely change your serialization method without altering your domain objects at all.  It should also be obvious how much easier the mapper is to test. But in many cases this pattern is also over-engineered and more than you need.  After all, most websites use the much simpler Active Record pattern.

Comment: I agree with you. I can certainly see the general point of the author, but saying that *all* static methods are impossible to test is a bit too hyperbolic IMO. :)

Comment: @deceze: it could make testing more difficult. Let's say you want to test the method that uses your static method. How could you mock it?

Comment: You will need to decide if the benefit of a more general pattern is worth the additional architecture complexity and lines of code.  Or, you can use an ORM that already uses a mapper pattern and can generate simple mappers for the common case, but still leave room for growth if you need it later.

Comment: @zerkms, OP could pass a mock `$pdo` object, because his static method felicitously use dependency injection.

Comment: @zerkms How do I test any code that uses `new User`? You can only abstract so far... :)

Comment: @deceze, you can dependency-inject the class names too! But point taken about abstracting too far ;)

Comment: @Francis Avila: your testing class should know implementation of the method used by the method you currently test. Way too deep. These tests will be fragile due to tight coupling to **implementation**

Comment: @deceze: you could mock a factory, that returns a user object. But you couldn't mock the static method. That's the key point

Comment: @Francis Avila: barely I could call "passing the class name" any sort of *dependency injection*.

Comment: @zerkms As I was afraid, this drifts towards a Factory pattern. Which is good and fine. I can accept that. That goes round in circles though, somewhere you need to instantiate that factory as well. There is something as too much abstraction, IMO.

Comment: @deceze: you just pass your factory by parameter (or use another way of decreasing your components coupling). There is no ideal solution indeed, but the truth is: with factory (or something that could retrieve user object) you could test method that uses it, and with static method - you couldn't. By saying "could" I mean that you are able to provide enough level of isolation

Comment: @zerkms, Classes aren't first class in PHP, so best that can be done is class name injection. The alternative is to pass an object with a factory method that the mapper knows how to use to create the object it needs. (Replaces `new $this->userclass($userargs)` with `$this->userfactory->create($userargs)`). Now you have *another* object and *another* class....

Comment: @Francis Avila: and that is much better, because in this case the separated class knows **what and how** to instantiate, and you can focus on business logic rather than on maintaining all the dependency tree :-)

Comment: @zerkms If I follow this to its logical conclusion, I need to instantiate *all* my objects that are used *anywhere* within my app somewhere at the global level and inject them all the way down, since I'm not allowed to construct any objects anywhere in any method. `new User` is a constructor, `User::getByPhone` is just an alternative constructor. You *have* to use them somewhere in methods without injecting them. :)

Comment: @deceze: oh... Your question was "how static methods make testing harder". I've given a sample. I could give another one without any instantiations, give me a second please

Comment: @zerkms I am asking how *this* particular static method is hard to test. I can see that if you have *only* static methods, you may have a problem. But then you're actually using *functional programming*, which is really easy to test, if you follow it to its logical conclusion. :)

Comment: Sometimes maintaining the dependency tree is easier than managing the complexity of a completely abstracted architecture. We have turned a simple User class that, ok, maybe has some hard to test bits, into an app requiring User, UserFactory, UserDBMapper, and defined interfaces between all three. If we don't need this much abstraction in the application, we have just strained out the gnat only to swallow a camel, and with more code comes even more code to *test*.

Comment: @deceze: here it is: http://pastebin.com/36kp3Q19. Which `TestMe` class is easier to test?

Comment: @deceze: " I can see that if you have only static methods, you may have a problem" -- no, even one tiny static method can make a lot of headache. See my sample

Comment: @deceze: to test the code that uses your `User::getByPhone()` - you need to have the live database with fixtures. This will make tests slow and dependant on the slow datasources. What if you decide to fill the user data from Facebook or Twitter profile?

Comment: @zerkms But I can mock the injected database layer!

Comment: @deceze: sure you can. And: a) for every test of `TestMe` (which directly doesn't use any database at all!!) you need to mock at least 3 PDO methods (!). b) If you decide to change from database to another storage, or just add another as addition (database + twitter + facebook) you need to change zillion tests and add mocks there as well. If you still think this != to "makes testing harder" then I don't have any more arguments ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: the general rule of thumb is: if creating of testing environment (in this case - it is creating mocks for all the datasources, or even mocking 3 methods of PDO) takes too much of time/lines of code (and involves knowledge of implementation details of dependent classes) - then your code is too tight coupled and you probably need to introduce some more abstraction (because too much of specifics now).

Comment: @zerkms Again, yes, I agree about the particular PDO implementation. My bad for including this as a point to latch onto in this example. The question is about the usage of `User::getByPhone(StorageAbstractionOfChoice, $id)` though, not about the particular usage of PDO (which again, can be abstracted more). But let's assume instead of `PDO`, I pass an instance of `IPermanentStorage`. How does that make `User::getByPhone` hard to test?

Comment: @deceze: I thought I was descriptive enough :-( Well, it is **easy** to test `User::getByPhone`, but it is **difficult** to test anything that uses `User::getByPhone`.

Comment: @zerkms Just as it's difficult to test anything that uses `new User`, but that doesn't mean we should or in fact can inject everything everywhere. But ok, we're going round in circles. Maybe I just hear what I want to hear, but I am still not convinced that this `static` method needs to be replaced with something else, since all alternatives seem equally problematic to me. I'd welcome if you could assemble all your arguments in one coherent answer, lets let the community vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the DateTime class was a good (tricky) class to choose because it is a horrible class.  All of its important work is done in the constructor and there is no way to set the date/time after it has been constructed.  This requires us to have an objectGenerator that can build the DateTime object at the correct time.  We can still manage this without calling new in the User class though.

I have kept things very simple to solve the problem at hand, but they can be extended easily to handle an arbitrarily complex problem.

Here is a simple objectGenerator to remove the coupling you get with `new`.

```
    class ObjectGenerator {
       public function getNew($className) {
          return new $className;
       }
    }
```

Now we inject all of the dependencies into the constructor.  The constructor shouldn't do real work, only set up the object.

```
class User {

    private $phone,
            $status = 'default',
            $created,
            $modified,
            $pdo,
            $objectGenerator;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, $objectGenerator) {
       $this->pdo = $pdo;
       $this->objectGenerator = $objectGenerator;
       $this->created = $this->objectGenerator->getNew('DateTime');
    }

    public function createNew() {
       $this->phone = '';
       $this->status = 'default';
       $this->created = $this->objectGenerator->getNew('DateTime');
    }

    public function selectByPhone($phone) {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `phone` = :phone');
        $stmt->execute(compact('phone'));
        if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
            return false;
        }

        $record         = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->phone    = $record['phone'];
        $this->status   = $record['status'];
        $this->created  = $record['created'];
        $this->modified = $record['modified'];
    }

    public function setPhone($phone) {
       $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function setStatus($status) {
       $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function save() {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO `users` (`phone`, `status`, `created`, `modified`)
                  VALUES         (:phone,  :status,  :created,  :modified)
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status`   = :status,
                                     `modified` = :modified');

    $modified = $this->objectGenerator->getNew('DateTime');

    $data = array(
            'phone'    => $this->phone,
            'status'   => $this->status,
            'created'  => $this->created->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'modified' => $modified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        return $stmt->execute($data);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$objectGenerator = new ObjectGenerator();

$pdo = new PDO();
// OR
$pdo = $objectGenerator->getNew('PDO');

$user = new User($pdo, $objectGenerator);
$user->setPhone('123456789');
$user->save();

$user->selectByPhone('5555555');
$user->setPhone('5552222');
$user->save();
```

So, **no new or static in the user class**.  Try testing both solutions.  The test code is a pleasure to write without the calls to new.  All classes that use the User will also be easy to test without static calls to it.

The differences in test code are:

**new/static**  - Require a stub for each new or static call to stop the unit from reaching outside of itself.

**dependency injection** - Mock objects can be injected.  It is painless.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. But this now allows the object to easily be put into an inconsistent state. I'm trying to model business rules with the `User` class, which works something like a FSM. The user can only be set into certain states (advance status etc) under certain conditions. Treating it like an Active Record just for the sake of one more abstraction level makes it much harder to enforce that. The static method in this case, as I said, acts as an *alternative constructor*, setting up the internal state from a serialized state.

Comment: And the `DateTime` thing is pretty much the only not injected object. And it's available by default in PHP and has very limited use, there's no need to abstract or mock it IMO.

Comment: I may have been too liberal with the public interface.  It could be replaced with only `createNew` and `selectByPhone`. It does require two lines ($user = new User(); $user->createNew();) to have a valid user, but you are the programmer.  You could choose to throw an exception when you try to do something on a user which is not yet valid.

Comment: If you want to use factories, I'd suggest a better factory that can use alternate constructors. Like `$objectGenerator->getNewWith('User', 'getByPhone', $pdo, 42)`. That makes it possible to write the `User` class in the way that makes the most sense *and* allows you to mock your factory. Static methods are not the problem.